# Get empty string from User.Identity.Name on vs2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

My computer has VS2008 and VS2013 installed. I have a website which was worked fine on VS2008. Recently I installed the VS2013 and update this website to be framework 4.5. I get the empty string of the User.Identity.Name in VS2013. I found some answer at [HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name empty when debugging in visual studio](http://HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name%20empty%20when%20debugging%20in%20visual%20studio)

I have  on webconfig. Also I make sure that I have the Windows Authentication component installed and activated in IIS. But I didn't see the Use Visual Studio Development Server in the "Properties" page. I only had option to use default Web Server.
[image]
 Does anyone tell me how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

The below is my code for debug.

```
 Dim Username As New User(User.Identity.Name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer from `[Authentication issue when debugging in VS2013 - iis express][1]`

there is answer

In VS2013 F4 on your project to view properties window and disable Anonymous access and enable "Windows authentication"